# python: using file handle to print contents of file

Tags: python, argparse, filehandle

I am following this advice: 
[File as command line argument for argparse - error message if argument is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11540854/file-as-command-line-argument-for-argparse-error-message-if-argument-is-not-va) 
to print the contents of a file. Here is an MWE:

```
import argparse
import os


def is_valid_file(parser, arg):
    """

    :rtype : open file handle
    """
    if not os.path.exists(arg):
        parser.error("The file %s does not exist!" % arg)
    else:
        return open(arg, 'r')  # return an open file handle


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='do shit')
parser.add_argument("-i", dest="filename", required=True,
                    help="input file with two matrices", metavar="FILE",
                    type=lambda x: is_valid_file(parser, x))

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.filename.read)
```

However, I am getting this instead of the file content:

```
<built-in method read of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x7f1988b3bb40>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace this :

```
print(args.filename.read)
```

to:

```
print(args.filename.read())
```

Read about Class and object here:
[Class and Object](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: @Zubo That is due to how python functions are first class objects. By typing filename.read you are getting an object. The `()` characters "call" the object. Note: `f = foo(); f.a = 4; f.a(); TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`